# What is different in setting a "Custom class" for a storyboard View Controller OR subclassing UIViewController and creating instances of that?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just created a simple Master-Detail app (SplitViewController).

If I create a New File - Objective-C class with the name MYCustomSplitViewController subclassing/inheriting from UISplitViewController I can do two things:

1. Go into Main.Storyboard, select the Split View Controller and set its "Custom Class" in the Identity Inspector to "MYCustomUISplitViewController"

   - Now, when the Split View Controller is loaded i get a "hit" inside MYCustomSplitViewController -viewDidLoad method.

In AppDelegate.m I have this, and one can clearly see that *splitViewController is an instance of UISplitViewController and not MYCustomUISplitViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
    return YES;
}
```

OR 2. Go into Main.Storyboard, select the Split View Controller and set its "Custom Class" in the Identity Inspector to "none" - it defaults to "UISplitViewController"

In AppDelegate.m I now modify *splitViewController to be a MYCustomUISplitViewController directly.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MYCustomUISplitViewController *splitViewController = (MYCustomUISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
    return YES;
}
```

In the second case I don't get a "hit" in the -viewDidLoad of MYUISplitViewController.

I don't get it... is MYUISplitViewController in this case only used for creating the instance *splitViewController and that's it? After that it doesn't access the methods any more? Does leaving the "Custom class" field empty actually tie it to some UISplitViewController that I can't see (Apple default)?

If so how does setting the "Custom class" in the first case tie the Instance on screen with the code in my file? How does UISplitViewController become the "Custom Class" for the Instance on screen when I clearly created an Instance of MYCustomUISplitViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you use in code is just a hint to the compiler about what you expect a variable to be. In your first example you declare

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Which you are confusing for meaning that this is an instance of `UISplitViewController`. To get the actual class log out `NSLog(@"%@", splitViewController.class)`. If you changed the custom class in the xib then the logged out class should be the custom class you set in the xib

Comment: "To get the actual class log out NSLog(@"%@", splitViewController.class). If you changed the custom class in the xib then the logged out class should be the custom class you set in the xib." I understand this part perfectly. I, kind of, understand the first part too.

Comment: Please elaborate the first part, I understand that I am giving a name "splitViewController" to an address, that address is in fact the address of the current object's window rootViewController. So if I understand this correctly then there is an object already there assigned as the rootViewController? If so where is this object created? Was this created using the Main.storyboard file? (so all that code is doing is referencing an existing object by a name in my code, so I can use it in code.

Comment: Yup the storyboard is responsible for creating this. This is set up in the project settings, where you set the storyboard to use. In this code you are as you say just grabbing a reference to this instance that came from the storyboard loading.

Comment: Great. I understand now. Please add these details explaining the first part to the answer, use part of my comment above and be very specific. I will mark it as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Added the clarifications myself. Please accept them and I will accept the answer. Tried to modify your answer as little as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Some peer reviewer decided against the edit. Would you be so kind and add this "You give the name "splitViewController" to an address, that address is in fact the address of the current (you are inside Appdelegate) object's, window, rootViewController. This object was already created by your Main.storyboard file since the split view controller there "Is Initial View Controller" was selected in the Attributes inspector, in Xcode. This is set up in the project settings, where you set the storyboard to use, you are just grabbing a reference to this instance that came from the storyboard loading."